# Can I use CiviRules to send a notification to the administrator when an email gets bounced?

Tags: civirules, bounce

Often when sending bulk mailings, a few addresses will bounce, for various reasons. these bounces are not very noticeable. In many cases the on hold flag doesn't get turned on, but in many cases it is important that some admins are alerted.

I'mnot too familiar with Civirules, but was wondering whether it could be used to send an email notification to admins whenever an email gets bounced from a bulk mailing, pointing them to the contact/s in question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this (at least without development). Most significantly, there isn't any trigger from within the bulk mail system in Civirules so you would not be able to catch the bounces that don't put the email on hold. I suspect that adding that functionality would be very difficult as I doubt that these email bounces go near the sort of things that Civirules for a trigger. There isn't even an option to catch the change to email on hold. The trigger "contact changed" with the condition "field value comparison" doesn't off the email on hold status as option, though I think adding this would be relatively straight forward if you want to write some code.